# Need help in worklight development

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have issue in calling api in worklight .
dont know how and where to call api.
need to get mobile imei number of the mobile .

I also need to get coordinates of mobile , Draw map using lt lg.

kindly help me .

Answer (score 0):

> know how and where to call api

That really depends on the API. Ask a proper question...
You need to mention what is your MobileFirst version, too...

> need to get mobile imei number of the mobile

This depends on the platform, for example Apple no longer allows to obtain the iPhone/iPad's IMEI number. For Android the following should work:

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(
   function(result) {
      console.log("result = " + result);
   },function() {
      console.log("error");
});
```

> Draw map using lt lg

Unclear what you're asking...

> get coordinates of mobile

Find a Cordova plug-in that provides this.